# Disable Products in different Magento Store Views

Tags: magento, store, product

I have a Magento Multi-Store installation (not multi-site) and some products are available in more than one store.  However, these products that are available in, let's say storeA and storeB, have related products, BUT, the related products are not available in both stores.

The problem is this, Product1, which has Product2, Product3, and Product4 as related products, appears in storeA.  No Problem.  Product1 is also available in storeB, but NOT Product2-3-4.  However, those products, though not shown in the general catalog of storeB, are visible as related products to Product1 in storeB.

If I use the drop down to manage products in storeB, and I remove the related products in Product1, it removes the related products from Product1 in storeA, where they should be available.

I cannot change the status attribute to storeview in Manage Attributes, because the only choices are Global or Website, not Store View.

I can change the skin to show UPSELL products instead, and set up different UPSELL products, but that limits my stores to only two.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

StoreViews are intended to have the same inventore, invoices, etc.

So you need to change your abstraction-layer to website to changes this

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control inventory per store-view, it's a Global setting.  You can control visibility and whether or not the product is enabled.  This line of code is how you can set to invisible per-store-view.

```
    $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NONE);
```

This is how you can set it to visible

```
    $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
```

Comment: This is more suitable as a comment.